# Horizontal Offset of One Pixel between Chrome and Safari with Absolute Positioned Element

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, css-position

My dropdown menu uses the following CSS:

```
header nav ul #sublist {
    height: 98px;
    width: 166px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 155px;
    top: 381px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

For some reason, the position is one pixel further to the right under Safari. It appears exactly where I want it to be with Chrome.

I've been investigating and can't find the source of this offset. You can see my website here:

http://www.theexpatcoach.com/b/

The dropdown menu is under 'Expat Coaching' on the nav bar.

Comment: Have you tried with translate? top and left 0 and set transform: translate3d('155px', '381px','0px')

Comment: @keypaul Thank you for the answer, tried it though and does not seem to work (appears very top-left of browser) as if no position was specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a `position: relative` on the parent `li` element:

```
header nav ul #expatSub {
  width: 166px;
  position: relative;
}
```

and set the `top` and `left` of your nested `ul` element relative from there:

```
header nav ul #sublist {
/* ... */
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 40px;
z-index: 1;
/* ... */
}
```